# Is there an update button?

Tags: updates, appcenter

I keep getting a notification that an update is available, but for some reason I  can't find where this update is. I checked all the apps in the app center and none indicate an update is available. Just before this happened I unintentionally uninstalled the app center, I reinstalled it and that is when I got the notification. Then restarted the pc and it gave me the notification again. I tried sudo apt update/upgrade and found a package for amd 64 which might have something to do with my cpu, but I don't think that is something that this OS (JUNO) would notify me of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please open [appcenter](/questions/tagged/appcenter) and click on Installed tab and you'll see the updates available. And please do installed updates they are necessary.

Comment: Thanks, after I turned the PC off and turned it on the next day, the update and the button showed up.